# Matlab trouble with display

Tags: matlab

I have a problem with matlab does not want me to display the results of this script says that I have a syntax error in the dispie but how to dispa correctly save because I tried in different ways and as it is saved now I got in the formula of the task.

```
clear; clc;
a=1; EA=2*10^5; EI=2*10^6; M=30;
A=[EA/a 0 0;
    0 12*EI/a^3 -6*EI/a^2;
    0 -6*EI/a^2  4*ei/3*a;]
P=[0;0;M];
U=A\P;
x=0:a/10:a;
u4=U(1);u5=U(2);u6=U(3)
uh=u4*x;
uv= u5*((3*x^2)/a^2 - (2*x^3)/a^3 + u6 - ((-(x)^2/a)+(x^3)/a^2)
disp([x',uh',uv']);
plot(x+uh,uv);
```

the same error is when i try to do that like this

```
clear; clc;
a=1; EA=2*10^5; EI=2*10^6; M=30;
A=[EA/a 0 0;
    0 12*EI/a.^3 -6*EI/a.^2;
    0 -6*EI/a.^2  4*EI/3*a;]
P=[0;0;M];
U=A\P;
x=0:a/10:a;
u4=U(1);u5=U(2);u6=U(3);
uh=u4*x;
uv= u5*((3*x^2)/a.^2 - (2*x^3)/a.^3 + u6 - ((-(x)^2/a)+(x^3)/a.^2);
disp([x',uh',uv']);
plot(x+uh,uv);
```

Comment: ***1.*** MATLAB is case-sensitive. so `EI` and `ei` are not same. ***2.*** There is a missing bracket in the declaration of `uv` ***3.*** Power of the matrix is possible only for square matrices. Please read the difference between matrix operations `^` and element-wise operations `.^` ***4.*** Please read the documentation of `disp` before using it.

Comment: Regarding the edit, please read my previous comment again

Answer (score 0):

I ran your program in Octave, and got error messages in your line 11:

```
uv= u5*((3*x^2)/a.^2 - (2*x^3)/a.^3 + u6 - ((-(x)^2/a)+(x^3)/a.^2);
```

The error message refered to a missing bracket. After adding a bracket,
I got a new error message:

```
error: for A^b, A must be a square matrix. Use .^ for elementwise power.
```

It seems to me that what you want is not matrix-powers for x, but pointwise
powers. After removing a lot of spurious brackets and replacing the matrix
powers with pointwise powers, I get

```
uv= u5*( 3*x.^2/a.^2 -  2*x.^3/a.^3 + u6 +     x.^2/a - x.^3/a.^2);
```

and now the program runs.